# How to create input page in Wordpress admin panel?

Tags: admin, forms

I have never used wordpress before and I'm trying to learn it now, I hope in this forum we can discuss about wordpress more, so I can more understand about it.

I have problem, that I want to create a input page for category but this form are located in admin panel. So, how to do it? especially about that steps.

Thank so much..

Comment: Sorry to say the StackExchange network is not a discussion forum.  It is a very specific question and answer resource.  Opinion based and general discussion posts rarely receive attention for members.

Answer (score 0):

Post categories are managed by the sub-menu item under "Post" on your site's admin menu.

Once logged in to the WP admin, goto Posts > Categories.

Comment: thanks for your respon,,, :)

I mind, how to make custome page so it can be seen on wordpress admin page? this page will be used to post data to database.

like make page using html, css and etc. for this case, i use wordpress to handle my website product, and this product have  many categories. I need form to post it to database.
Sorry i'm new in wordpress customizing.

Comment: If you are adding products and you would like to categorize these, I would explore the documentation for Custom Post Types. http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types